# Updating a HashMap in such a way that the 2nd value becomes 1st and 3rd becomes 2nd and so on

Tags: java

I have an object with 5 fields as Strings named `String1` to `String5`.
When I remove `String1` from the object, I have to update the values such that `String1` will have `String2` value and so on and `String5` will become `null`.

Say we have a HashMap as below,

```
HashMap<Integer,String>
```

It has 5 values. Keys 1 to 5 and corresponding String values.
Now if we have to remove the 1st value such that the 2nd value will become the 1st and 3rd will become 2nd and so on.
How can we achieve this ?

eg: HashMap has

```
(1,"Art")
(2,"Math")
(3,"Science")
(4,"History")
(5,"Physics")
```

Now I have to delete the 1st value, then the HashMap will be

```
(1,"Math")
(2,"Science")
(3,"History")
(4,"Physics")
(5,null)
```

If I have to delete the 2nd value, then the 1st one will remain the same, but the lower order will be change as follows

```
(1,"Art")
(2,"Science")
(3,"History")
(4,"Physics")
(5,null)
```

Comment: hashmap doesn't support ordering

Comment: `HashMap` has no defined iteration order so it is not correct to refer to 1st, 2nd, 3rd values.

Comment: The Keys will always be from 1 to 5 Integers. The String value will keep on changing.

Comment: You probably want a `TreeMap` then. It keeps the keys in (numerical) order.

Comment: I dont need an order for the Keys. Say i want to delete the 1st value, whose key will always be Integer 1, then i will put the 2nd value in the 1st one.

Comment: An `ArrayList<String>` satisfies your requirements.

Comment: Probably you do not want to do what you ask, your problem is another one and you think you will solve it with this question (see "XY problem").

Comment: Using a `Map` for this is just causing more effort and problems than necessary... You would have to update all the entries on every removal of a value... Don't... Use a `List`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, i have updated the question so we could understand the problem better

Comment: A map with contiguous integer keys is just a list in disguise

Comment: The only difference (to the `Map` provided in the question) is the index of a `List` beginning at `0` while the keys show here start at `1`. Should be kept in mind, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you might be better off using a `List<String>`

```
private static List<String> removeTopic(List<String> topics, String topic) {
    List<String> topicsCopy = new ArrayList<>(topics);
    topicsCopy.remove(topic);
    topicsCopy.add(null);
    return topicsCopy;
}
```

Then:

```
List<String> topics = Arrays.asList("Art", "Math", "Science", "History", "Physics");
System.out.println(topics);

topics = removeElement(topics, "Math");
System.out.println(topics);
```

> [Art, Math, Science, History, Physics]
>
> [Art, Science, History, Physics, null]

Comment: Right, will look into it and complete my answer for that

Comment: @Andy simply `topics.add(null)` actually

Comment: But the remove will give Concurrent modification exception as i have to delete a String which will match the one in the ArrayList and then populate my original Object with the updated values in the ArrayList

Comment: I wont get the index to be removed, rather the String value which has to be removed

Comment: @RohitT I changed to delete by topic name, also I make a copy of the array so there is no issue with modifying it

Comment: @RohitT Also I would advise against adding the `null` at the end if it is not a requirement?

Comment: -- @Bentaye..Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
      Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>(Map.of(1,"Art", 2, "Math",
                        3,"Science", 4,"History", 5,"Physics")); 
      System.out.println(map);
      delete(2,map);
      System.out.println(map);

      public static void delete(int key, Map<Integer,String> map) {
      for (int i = key; i <= map.size(); i++) {
            map.put(i, map.get(i+1));
      }
```

But there is no reason to do so. Your keys imply a linear ordering which will certainly work.  But why not just use a `List` of values and simply delete them with the built in methods?

Then you don't need a fancy method to do so.  You can just do it like this.

```
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of("Art", "Math", "Science", "History", "Physics"));
  System.out.println(list);
  list.remove("Math");
  System.out.println(list);
```

If you really want a null value at the end you can add it.  But it serves little value as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But yes a List would be more appropriate here

Answer (score -1):

```
private Map<Integer, String> values = new HashMap<>();

public void add(String s) {
    values.put(values.size(), s);
}

public void remove(int slot) {
    for (int i = slot; i <= values.size(); i++) {
        if (i == slot) {
            values.remove(slot);
        } else {
            String s = values.get(i);
            values.put(i - 1, s);
            values.remove(i);
        }
    }
    values.put(values.size(), null);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main4 m = new Main4();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        m.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }
    System.out.println(m.values);
    m.remove(3);
    System.out.println(m.values);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but a List would be more appropriate to this i guess.